# how to load external content in a div and then display it in a lightbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to load external content in a div and then display it in a lightbox using jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** method

Comment: yeah thats fine,then do i use a lightbox plugin to display it in a lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

As rahul said you would be best to use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to fetch the external content and then find a lightbox plugin that you like and use that to display the data.  There are lots to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution can be found at [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)